# recall or delete email as office 365 admin

Tags: email, office365

we had a user send out a email that needs to be deleted or recalled

I am the admin of our company in office 365 and the email only went to people in our domain

what is the best way to delete it?

Comment: What client are you using to access Office 365? Outlook? Or the Web client?

Comment: both, the user is not accessible to do the work I wanted to recall it from the admin exchange portal if possible

Comment: the easiest (probably only way) to do it is from Outlook, as the user. then Actions -> recall message.

Comment: that's what we did but it imply that the users i going to be helpful and not outright hostile to your actions. I can't believe there inst away to remove an email force ably as the admin

Comment: @techie007 answer the question with recall instructions an i will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest (probably only way) to do a proper recall is from a full Outlook 2010+ client, while logged in as the user.

Then just open the sent email, and them Message tab -> Actions -> Recall message.

More Info: [Recall or replace an email message that you sent](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/recall-or-replace-an-email-message-after-it-is-sent-HA010354931.aspx)

There's no way to recall a message via Outlook Web Access at this time (that I'm aware of).

If you have PowerShell access to the Exchange server, you could use PS to search for all messages in a mail database with a specific title, from a specific user, in a specific date range, and delete those.

More Info: [Search-Mailbox cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Comment: as a note: You have to log into Outlook as the user who sent out the original email.  It can be done from any PC and you'll get the recall option.  I tried to attach the user's mailbox to my own and was not able to recall this way. (even though I had full access.)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an email across all users accounts with PowerShell if you are using Office 365.  Refer to this article:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-for-and-delete-email-messages-in-your-Office-365-organization-Admin-Help-3526fd06-b45f-445b-aed4-5ebd37b3762a

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it [would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.